# Xcode not showing some of my View Controllers on Commit (GitHub)

Tags: xcode, git, github, commit, viewcontroller

I'm new to using github and am trying to put my xcode project on there. The project is actually on github now but its basically a blank project. I want to update it to its current version by using commit but only 3 of my 13 view controllers actually show up when I commit. the other 10 don't even show up to be checked.

When I started this project I clicked and dragged view controllers from my old project and noticed that a lot of these that I moved from an old project are not showing up when I commit. Also should I push? I'm not really sure what push does ether and I don't want to lose my work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I'll leave this up if anyone else has a problem. Check your file path, click a view controller, top right side it says the location of the file and the path. If your like me I had the files literally in 4 different places on my computer just organize them in your main file, reset the paths, try not to delete anything and it should work. Let me know